# How to change a hostname

Tags: debian, hostname

During Debian installation, I set my hostname to the wrong value, and now I would like to correct that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The hostname is stored in three different files:

- `/etc/hostname` Used as the hostname
- `/etc/hosts` Helps resolving the hostname to an IP address
- `/etc/mailname` Determines the hostname the mail server identifies itself

You might want to have a deeper look with `grep -ir hostname /etc`

Restarting affected services might be a good idea as well.

Answer (score 3):

The value is stored in `/etc/hostname`. After modifying, apply it with `/etc/init.d/hostname start`

Comment: This fails in Debian 6. Which version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Various services may also depend on being able to resolve the hostname locally, which is often handled by an entry in the /etc/hosts file.